# Angularjs: How To Call Controller Function After Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning angularjs and there is one aspect of it that I'm struggling to understand.

My desired/expected behavior of the code below is:

- User clicks the Paris link (anchor tag)
- The routeProvider intercepts the request, loads the paris.html page into the ng-view.
- The 'getCity' function in the controller gets the data and sets the scope variables, which are displayed in the london.html expressions.

However, I can't figure out how to config angularjs to use the 'getCity' function when the html page is loaded into the ng-view. The closest I can get is calling the 'getCity' function from within the CityController itself, bit this seems to have the undesired effect of calling the function when the whole app (index.html) is loaded instead of only when the link is clicked. The controller will have a number of different functions.

I also know you can use ng-click to call a controller's function, but I'm unsure how this would work with loading a html page into an ng-view through the route provider.

Any help would be appreciated. Please see code below from a small app built for learning purposes:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>


</head>
<body>


        <ol>

            <li><a href="#/cities/paris">Paris</a></li>

        </ol>


        <div class="content-wrapper" ng-controller="CityController">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>


        <script src="resources/js/app.js"></script>

        <script src="resources/js/CityController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("mainApp", [ 'ngRoute' ]);

app.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.

    when('/cities/paris', {
        templateUrl : 'resources/paris.html',
        controller : 'CityController'
    }).


    otherwise({
        redirectTo : ''

    });


} ]);
```

**CityController.js**

```
app.controller('CityController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getCity = function() {

        $http.get('city')
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.name = response.name;
            $scope.country = response.country;
        }).error(function() {
            //Output error to console 
        });

    };

     //$scope.getCity();

});
```

I don't want to call getCity here because it means the http get request to 
the 'city' endpoint is called when index.html is loaded

**paris.html**

```
This is Paris.
<br><br><br>
Name: {{name}}<br>
Country: {{country}}
<br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the router `resolve` option.

> A resolve contains one or more promises that must resolve successfully before the route will change. This means you can wait for data to become available before showing a view, and simplify the initialization of the model inside a controller because the initial data is given to the controller instead of the controller needing to go out and fetch the data.

Check the explanation and usage [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can call getCity() from paris.html using ,ng-init=getCity() ,ng-init will call your function as soon as paris.html is loaded into your ng-view .
For Eg.

```
This is Paris.
<br><br><br>
 <div ng-init=getCity() >
  Name: {{name}}<br>
  Country: {{country}}
 </div>
<br><br><br>
```